# Facing Error: input is a void element tag and must neither have `children` nor use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`. while creating a simple form

Tags: reactjs

I'm learning ReactJS. I'm creating a simple form in React. Here's my login component:

```
function Login() {
    return (
        <div className="card login-container">
            <form id="login">
                <label><input name="email" className="email" placeholder="Email" type="text"></input></label>
                <label><input name="password" className="password" placeholder="Password" type="password"></input></label>
                <label><input type="submit" className="btn btn-submit">Submit</input></label>
            </form>
        </div>
    )
}
```

**I'm getting this error:**

> Error: input is a void element tag and must neither have `children` nor use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`.

I found out a couple of solutions on StackOverflow. I learned that I shouldn't be containing children. So, I wrapped my inputs in . Also, I made the form controlled thinking React may not allow uncontrolled forms. Still, it's showing the same error. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks :)

Comment: I see you have a submit button, so use a `button` with `type="submit"` instead of input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like the error states, the `input` is a void element and as such it can't contain any nested elements.

Also, the way to supply display text to a `input[type=submit]` element is to use the `value` attribute of the element.

```
function Login() {
    return (
        <div className="card login-container">
            <form id="login">
                <label><input name="email" className="email" placeholder="Email" type="text" /></label>
                <label><input name="password" className="password" placeholder="Password" type="password" /></label>
                <label><input type="submit" className="btn btn-submit" value="Submit" /></label>
            </form>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Note that this is not simply a **reactjs** related issue. Yes, in this particular case **react** warns you that you're doing a mistake but generally enclosing/nesting elements into void elements makes your **HTML** invalid. So this is more of a HTML/semantic issue.